# Javascript - clean user inputted money value

Tags: javascript, parsing, numbers

How can I properly clean a money Value that is inputted by the user?

I need the value as a Big Decimal, but the input field for the user is a standard text input.
I am trying to format the string, however, I can not find a way to do it cleanly for all variations a user usually inserts.

I tried this:

```
parseFloat(amount.replace(',', '.')
```

This works in the following cases:

```
1000 -> 1000
1000.1 -> 1000.1
1000,1 -> 1000.1
```

However, I have the following two cases that do not work currently:

```
1,000.1 -> gives: 1.1 / should be: 1000.1
1.000,1 -> gives 1.1 / should be: 1000.1
```

Is there a way to format the string so it also works if the user inputs one or more commas or dots as decimal seperators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
function parse(str){
  if(str.includes('.') && str.includes(',')){
    str = str.split(/[.,]/)
    let last = str.lastIndexOf('.') || str.lastIndexOf(',');
    return parseFloat(str.slice(0,last).join('').replace(/[.,]/g,'') + '.' + str.slice(last)) 
  }
  else return str.replace(',','.');
}
console.log(parse('1.000,1'))
console.log(parse('1,000.1'))
console.log(parse('1,0000'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the code needs to differentiate between the decimal separator and the thousand's separator. There can only be one decimal separator and it's usually the last '.' or ',' in the input. You can replace only the last ',' in the string with a '.' and remove all the rest ',' and '.' from the input. That would work for the test cases you provided, but if the user inputs something like 100,001 and the ',' is intended as a thousand's separator, the code will still fail. Best way in my opinion is to use an input mask of some sort or a help paragraph denoting the correct input value type.

Comment: Is there maybe a regex that could try this from the other way around? E.g: check if the last Instance of either dot or comma is followed by 1 or 2 signs -> if yes, it's the decimal seperator, but if it is followed by 3 signs it is the thousands seperator?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my working suggestion with 10 test cases:

```js
    const getCorrectValue = (value = 0) => {
      return (''+value)
        .replace(',','.')
        .match(/.\d*/g)
        .map((val, i, arr) => {
          return (i < arr.length - 1)
            ? val.replace(/[,|\.]/g, '')
            : val
        })
        .join('');
    }

    const testCases = [
      getCorrectValue() === "0",
      getCorrectValue(1.0) === "1",
      getCorrectValue("1") === "1",
      getCorrectValue("1,0") === "1.0",
      getCorrectValue("1.0") === "1.0",
      getCorrectValue(1.1) === "1.1",
      getCorrectValue("1,1") === "1.1",
      getCorrectValue("1.1") === "1.1",
      getCorrectValue("1,000.1") === "1000.1",
      getCorrectValue("1.000.1") === "1000.1",
      getCorrectValue("1,000.000.1") === "1000000.1",
    ];

console.log('Test pass', testCases.map((testCase, i) => (testCase) ? `${i} pass` : `${i} fails`));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you think your solution is more reliable or faster then the accepted one? Both seem to work with the cases I tried.

Comment: I can't evaluate that. I just posted this since I spent like 10mins of writing it, and meanwhile the accepted answer popped out :). But I decided to post it just in case that you (or someone else) has some edge cases on formatting that were not taken consideration in the approved answer.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it!